# PHP, refresh page on insert

Tags: php, mysql

this is the updating function:

```
public function update($id) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $stmt9 = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET `name`= :name, `email`= :email WHERE `id` = :id");


        $stmt9->bindParam(':name', $this->name);
        $stmt9->bindParam(':email', $this->email);
        $stmt9->bindParam(':id' , $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt9->execute();
        if ($stmt9) {
           $message = "User updated Sussesfully!";
            header('location:');
        }else {
            header("location:");
        }
        }
    }
```

Now on update here i want the page to be refresh so i could see the updated data, but here now if it update it's will keep user in edite page, and will show the data of privous entered if i see in database the data has been updated and if i refresh the page with f5 it will show the on edit page is been update with out that when i submit the form it will get update but on the form it will show the prevouse data,

so how i can make the page to get refresh after submitting. on redirection if if redirect to list page it will show that it's been updated, but here i want on mean time stay on edit page and reaload page so i could see the updated data.

regards

Comment: always remember to `exit;` or `die;` after `header('location:...')` the script will continue to run after the browser has been redirected!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple:

```
header('Refresh: 0'); // 0 = seconds
```

Even you can specify new location

```
header("Refresh:2; url=new_page.php");
```

But when working with `header` function there should not be anything echoed before calling it,
but if you have already echoed anything, then you can use html or javascript:

**HTML**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">
<!--here you can also specify new url location-->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://url.com/">
```

**JS**

```
window.location.reload();
```

**Update:** because you can't use `header` do this:

```
if ($stmt9) 
{
    $message = "User updated Sussesfully!";
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">';
 }
else 
{
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">';
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I tried to do `header('Location: ' . $url);` but it complained about redirections after 20 redirects whereas your `header('Refresh:0; url=' . $url);` does the job perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1):

you should redirect to update url rather than reload
eg.

```
  header("location:updateurl?id=1");
```

Comment: Please note the browser will complain after 20 redirects. If that matters for anyone then @George's solution is a good workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using jquery.

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: indeed that does not need jQuery, even you are not representing usage of it

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to redirect to the exactly same page, you can use variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

```
header('location:' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```

This code is familiar with re-write rules if any.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (ou

You need to switch on output buffering in PHP. If this option is enabled, then you need check if your code doesn't flush output buffer somewhere earlier.

Comment: Please note the browser will complain after 20 redirects. If that matters for anyone then @George's solution is a good workaround.

Answer (score -1):

Its simple, change this code:

```
if ($stmt9) {
    $message = "User updated Sussesfully!";
    header('location:');
}else {
    header("location:");
}
```

like this

```
if ($stmt9) {
    $message = "User updated Sussesfully!";
    header('location: ?message='.$message);
}else {
    header("location: ?message=error");
}
```

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (ou

Comment: @Se Kh, This will rewrite previous GET parameters such as ?id=15