# Refresh a page on insertion of data in the database

Tags: php, mysqli, page-refresh

I'm using PHP/MySQLi for backend. I want to refresh a page everytime when there has been data insertion in the database. 
Is there anyway to do this. Please let me know if you have something.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP, refresh page on insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662908/php-refresh-page-on-insert)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

Or:

```
header("Refresh:0; url=page2.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

use this after insert query enter data:-

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">';
```